# Ajax not working properly in UAE countries

Tags: jquery, ajax

[image]I am conflicting very strange issue.

I implemented Ajax post using jquery.
It is working well now.
But when I change the country to israel using vpn, Ajax post is not working.
http://www.neomnews.net/LP/elmubasher/?camp=6

This is backend

```php
   public function register(){
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

        $req = array();
        $params = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $req = json_decode($params, true);

        $user = array();
        $user['email'] = $req['email'];
        $user['username'] = $req['firstname']." ".$req['lastname'];
        $user['password'] = $req['password'];
        $user['phone_number'] = $req['phone_number'];
        $user['country'] = $req['country'];
        $user['user_type'] = 2;
        $user['register_url'] = $req['register_url'];
        //$user['url_name'] = $req['url_name'];
        $user['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', time());

        $response = array();

        $response['request'] = $req;
        $response['data'] = $this->client_model->add_user($user);
        if(count($response['data']) > 0){
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Add user Success.";
        }else{
            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "Database add failed.";
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

```
 $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'http://neomnews.net/crm/api/register',
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: JSON.stringify({
                      "email":EmailAddress,
                      "firstname": FirstName,
                      "lastname": LastName,
                      "password":"test",
                      "phone_number": PhoneNumber,
                      "country": Country,
                      "register_url":window.location.href,
                      "url_name": "ANA_OMAR_TWITTER"
                  }),
                  success: function(response){
                      swal({
                          type: 'success',
                          title: 'شكرا جزيلا لتسجيلك!',
                          html: 'سيتم الاتصال بك لاحقا'
                      });        
                  },
                  error: function(err){
                    sweetAlert("حدث خطأ الرجاء المحاولة مرة اخرى", "error");
                  }                        
                });
```

It shows me CORS error.
But this error isn't showed when I try with Europe countries.
I use CodeIgniter framework.

[image]

Comment: try to add `crossOrigin: true` in your ajax call.

Comment: sorry, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

This is what you can try to work out a solution:

- Implement CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)
- Use JSONP (JSON Padding)

Also, look at this:
http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html

Comment: sorry, I can't figure out. As I mentioned, it's working well when I try with European countries.